# Access Protected Method from Plugin Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fatal error: Call to undefined method CookieComponent::del()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890610/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-cookiecomponentdel)

I am creating a plugin that uses a login method from my SiteUsers controller, but I am getting the error message:

> Call to undefined method SiteUsersController::_doLogIn()

**Plugin Site Users Controller:**

```
class SiteUsersController extends AppController {

public $name = 'SiteUsers';


/**
 * login_competition
 *
 */
public function login_challenge() {

    $this->autoRender = false;

    if (!$this->_doLogIn($this->request->data['SiteUser'])) {

            $this->Session->setFlash('ERROR');

        }

    }

    $this->redirect('/');
}

}
```

**Site User Controller in main App**

```
class SiteUsersController extends AppController {

public $name = 'SiteUsers';

/**
 * _doLogIn()
 *
 * @param unknown_type $data
 * @return string|string
 */
protected function _doLogIn($data) {

    $this->_user = $this->SiteUser->getUserByEmailPassword(Sanitize::clean($data));

    if (!empty($this->_user)) {

        $this->Session->Write('SiteUser.id', $this->_user['SiteUser']['id']);
        $this->Session->Write('SiteUser.first_name', $this->_user['SiteUser']['first_name']);
        $this->Session->Write('SiteUser.username', $this->_user['SiteUser']['username']);

        return true;
    }

    return false;

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to move your _doLogIn into component. That way you don't have to make it public and users won't get to it directly through browser and it will be available to all controllers.

Current _doLogIn could be rewritten to use new components method so sitewide there is no big deal if it is used widely.

Just in case ;) http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html

Comment: It is impossible for users to access protected methods as actions in Cake. Besides that, Components are the way to go.